# How do I avoid the array bound error with JTables?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, tablemodel

Well my question is fairly simple, I have put a `JTable` in a `JFrame`, but I want that the table to automatically resizes according the size of an `ArrayList` or to have a side scroll bar

For example if I do something like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    jTable1.getModel().setValueAt(list.getVar(i),i,0);
}
```

If my `ArrayList` has 10 elements and my `JTable` was set up to 4 elements I got the arraybound error. Is there a way to put a scroll bar or something in the `JTable` so it can shows all the rows that I want (depending on the size of the `ArrayList` of course)?

Comment: `If my ArrayList has 10 elements and my JTable was set up to 4 elements` - you should NOT be trying to manipulate an ArrayList. Data is stored in the TableMdodel. If you change the data in the model then scrollbars will appear automatically. Start by using the DefaultTableModel. You can use the addRow(...) method to dynamically add rows to the model.

Answer (score 0):

Set the number of rows in the table before you run your code:

```
((DefaultTableModel)(jTable1.getModel())).setRowCount(list.size());
```

[`DefaultTableModel` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

If you want to put the `JTable` in a scroll box, when you add it to the container you have to say

```
container.add(new JScrollPane(jTable1));
```

instead of

```
container.add(jTable1);
```

Comment: thanks @Jakob Weisblat, but about the scroll, is there any way to put that in a jTable?

Comment: I added to my answer what I think you want.

Comment: reason for asking for an SSCCE, why guessing, maybe you are right, maybe not, OPs descriptions are soo diff to their actual code, 50:50 ???